# How to Use conceptual dependencies , predicate calculus/logic , conceptual graph in NLP

Tags: search, nlp, artificial-intelligence

How to Solve This Problem ..?
Using

- conceptual dependencies
- predicate calculus/logic
- conceptual graph

  to represent the following sentences
- a)   All dogs bark.
- b)   No school buses are purple.
- c)   Some drivers do not obey the speed limit
- d)   Mary borrows a book with red cover from the library.
- f)   Every book is either an encyclopedia or a dictionary but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a homework assignment. If it is, I'd love to know more about the class. It seems to be one I would like to know the professor etc.

Because it amuses me, I'll try one of these.

All dogs bark.

this seems to be an English form of the predicate calculus.

forall ((x Dog)) (bark x).

assuming that Dog is defined as a proper category and bark is an appropriate predicate.

I can't help with the Conceptual Dependency representation unless you share what set of primitives you have to work with. Do you use PTRANS and MTRANS ? Is the air moving from a bark considered to be a physical object moved ? We need more definition to understand what you are trying to do.

Why did you not include DRS ? It seems to be a very common representation in  many NLP applications currently.

Which syntax for Conceptual graphs are you using? the original John Sowa set from 1984? What grammar do you need to use ? CGIF ? Common Logic ?

Best Wishes,
David